# Find the Instantaneous Velocity at $t=4 (s'(4))$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm not sure how to find the instantaneous velocity using the limit definition.

The original problem is find the height of a ball when launched from a building. $s(t)$ in meters and $t$ in seconds.

$$s(t) = -4.9t^2 + 30t + 20$$

Find average velocity between $[1, 4]$, which I found to be $5.5$ meters per second.

Not sure how to find the instantaneous velocity using the limit definition at $t=4$, that is, $s'(4)$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $s'(t)=-9.8 t+30$ Plug in $t=4$. Note that the derivative at $t$ gives the *rate of change of height* at time $t$ which is the definition of instantaneous velocity

Comment: That's not using the limit definition.

Comment: You should check your average velocity calculation, which should be $\frac{s(4)-s(1)}{4-1}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read 'by definition'

Comment: Just updated it with correct average velocity.

Comment: @androidguy.  I think you forgot to subtract the $s(1)$ term in the numerator.

Comment: Okay, tried it again. Got 5.5 meters per second for avg. See my comment on your answer below for inst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s'(4)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{s(4+h)-s(4)}{h}$.

Note that $s(4+h)=-4.9(4+h)^2+30(4+h)+20$.

You have to crank through some algebra!

Comment: Okay thanks. So after simplifying I got (120.4 + 25.1h) / (h). So then cancel h's somehow?

Comment: There's still a problem: $s(4+h)=-4.9(16+8h+h^2)+(120+30h)+20$.  If all goes well, you should be able to cancel a factor of $h$ top and bottom of your limit fraction.

Comment: Oh right, didn't expand correctly. Thanks. I'll work on it again. So once you cancel the factors, you are left with the limit which you can plug in 4 to get the answer, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work!